# detect when UIImageView finished scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a tall UIImageView scrolling across the screen when a button is pressed. I used a timer to change the y position of the image at a specific speed. The image is 10,000px tall.
Here's my simple code:

```
-(void) moveImage {

myImage.center = CGPointMake(myImage.center.x, myImage.center.y +6);

}

-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender{

moveImageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self     selector:@selector(moveImage)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[StartGame setHidden:TRUE];
}
```

Here's what i've tried to stop the timer when the image has scrolled completely through the screen:

```
-(void) moveImage {

myImage.center = CGPointMake(myImage.center.x, myImage.center.y +6);

if ([myImage == GPointMake(myImage.center.x, myImage.center.y -568) {
    [moveImageTimer invalidate];
}
```

That doesn't work but i thought it would. Can someone tell me why the IF statement doesn't work? Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: maybe check for myImage.center in your if statement

Comment: Show the code which sets image view in your controller..also you are comparing object of image with center..

Comment: That `if` statement won't compile. 568 is not a multiple of 6. Repeatedly adding a positive number to a float will never result in a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to stop when the image moves to the bottom corner.

```
    -(void) moveImage {

       CGPoint newPoint= CGPointMake(myImage.center.x, myImage.center.y +6);

        myImage.center = newPoint;
        if ((newPoint.y - (myImage.frame.size.width/2)) >= [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)
        {
            [moveImageTimer invalidate];
        }

    }
```

Comment: The thing is, my image is 10,000px tall. If i used the way you just told me, it makes the image stop before the whole image has scrolled through the screen. I need a way to detect when the whole 10,000px image has scrolled entirely through the screen... Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the condition 
like if (imageView.center.y > imageView.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height)

here  imageView.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height because the image size is twice screen size. You have to set you logic

imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, imageView.center.y + 6);

```
if (imageView.center.y > imageView.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height)
{
    [moveImageTimer invalidate];
}
```

}